# Webhook method is processed faster than controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, webhooks

In my application there is payment by Stripe.

When I click on "Pay" button, there must be processing through controller. Webhook is also running at the same time.

The problem is that the method in response to the web hook is faster than the action in my controller.

How to slow down a method for webhook so that action in controller is first processed?

*Webhook:*

```
ev = Stripe::Webhook.construct_event(...)
case ev.type
when "invoice.created"
  change_invoice(ev)
when "invoice.payment_succeeded"
  invoice_paid(ev)
```

`change_invoice(ev)` is faster than my controller.

Comment: I experienced a similar problem, in my case I was passing the data received in the web hook to a background job. If it was "too soon", the job could re-queue another job w/the same data to be run in a few seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I can think of is using a database lock. Have a read here: https://www.peterdebelak.com/blog/pessimistic-locking-in-rails-by-example/

Assuming that Event is a model you defined:

```
  # Controller action
  def create
   ev = Event.create(some_params)
   ev.lock!
   # Do the stripe processing here
   # When you are done with your controller work:
   ev.save # will release the lock
  end

  # Then in your webhook processor
  def process
    ev = Event.find(some_id) # This will wait until the lock is released in the controller thread. Just be aware that if the controller doesn't release the lock within the timeout limit, this will raise an exception
    # now you can process the event because the controller is done
  end
```